# How to turn off JSLint indentation warnings?

Tags: formatting, static-analysis, jslint

I find that [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) produces lots of warnings of the form:

```
Expected 'foo' to have an indentation at X instead at Y.
```

The [JSLint options documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) describes an `indent` option that recognizes a numerical value representing the amount of space for each level of indentation. This option allows me to say things like use 2 spaces per level of indentation. I just write something like this at the top of my JavaScript file:

```
/*jslint indent: 2 */
```

OK, great. Now JSLint knows how much to indent for each level of indentation, *but JSLint seems to be hardcoded to decide what level of indentation each line should have*.

**Suppose I want to indent my code differently than the way JSLint prescribes. Can I do this with some JSLint option? If not, can I at least turn off the indentation warnings?** I tried:

```
/*jslint indent: false */
```

but that did not cause indentation warnings to be elided; it caused a JSLint error.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What a difference that morning coffee makes:

```
/*jslint white: true */
```

Comment: Of course, this still doesn't addressthe issue of specifying another formatting style.

Comment: This only worked for me when I had /* jslint white: true */ which is odd.

Comment: I am trying to configure this in Sublime 2? Do you always have to add this on top of your JS files - or it can be globally set for JSLint plugin in Sublime?

Comment: This says it needs to be set to true: http://jslinterrors.com/expected-exactly-one-space-between-a-and-b

Comment: @synthesizepatel (Your comment is three years old now, but just for the records:) `/* jslint white: true */` won't work because jslint requires to be no space between the opening block comment (`/*`) and the keyword `jslint`. Basically: `/* jslint` is wrong, `/*jslint` is right.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to disable JSLint, you can remove the double indentations (e.g. when defining multiple var's in a javascript file) by adjusting this setting:

Options > Editor > Formatting > Language: Javascript > Continuation Indentation - set to 4.

Now you can use ctrl shift f to format code, and JSLint doesn't freak out...

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear. I was using Netbeans 8.0